# Resetting the Last_NUMBER in sequence by looking up a value from a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, sequence

I have a sequence called SEQ_SYNTAX. I need to set the last_number value of this sequence by looking up a value from another table called INCREMENTS. I can get the value from increments table by doing SELECT LASTVAL FROM INCREMENTS WHERE TABLE = 'SYNTAX';

How do I write a simple SQL script that can set that sequence value? say if the lastval from increments table where table = 'SYNTAX' is 3000, I want to set the last_number for sequence SEQ_SYNTAX to be 3000.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 12c, you can simply reset the starting value. Doing it programmatically will require PL/SQL so we have to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` since an `ALTER SEQUENCE` is a DDL:

```
   DECLARE
     var_sequence_name varchar2(128) := 'SEQ_SYNTAX';
     var_new_value integer;
   BEGIN
     SELECT MAX(lastval)
       INTO var_new_value
       FROM increments
      WHERE "TABLE" = 'SYNTAX';
      
     IF var_new_value > 0
     THEN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'alter sequence "'||var_sequence_name||'" restart start with '||v_new_value;
     END IF;
   END;
```

If you are pre-12c you will have to drop and recreate the sequence if the new value is lower than the current value, or dummy-advance with a script until it reaches the new value if the new value is larger. That was a hassle, so we're grateful for the 12c enhancement.

Comment: We're on Oracle 19

Comment: I am not familiar with Oracle PL/SQL way of writing this script. Please help.

Comment: @rvpals, edited my answer with a fuller script based on your details

Comment: How do I turn this into a function that I can call repeatedly from My Oracle SQL script. I want to pass in the sequence name, and the 2nd parameter as name of the table.  I want to be able to call function(SEQ1, 'SYNTAX'); call function(SEQ2, 'NUMBER'); The function will put 2nd parameter into "TABLE" = 'NUMBER', and update the specific sequence name (passed in 1st parameter)

Comment: Replace `DECLARE` with `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_reset_sequence(var_sequence_name IN varchar2, var_table_name IN varchar2) AS` and also change `"TABLE"` in the query to `var_table_name`.